# Parallelism not engaging on specific database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, maxdop

I have a few databases with identical schema, lets call:

- DB_A
- DB_B

I have a query that when run takes 11 seconds and returns 11K (11000) records on DB_A but when the exact same query is run on the identical DB_B it takes 40 seconds and returns 7K (7000) records.

The schema is identical, but when i run it on DB_B it runs on Degree of Parallelism 1, on DB_A it runs on 16.

I tried setting the cost of threshold to 0 to force parallelism but got the same result.

Why is that? How can the same query running on cloned databases behave so differently?

Any ideas are welcome. I'm using SQL 2017 Standard.

Comment: Can you show us , the execution plan ?  the query? also you can try with `OPTION(MAXDOP X)`, where x = 1 or 2 .4... and see the estimate cost of your query; +  you don't have limitations/restrictions on your workload

Comment: Yes I tried that, set it to maxdop 0 and 16, same result, what kind of limitations could I have? Where would o check?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-workload-group-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 , see the part with `MAX_DOP = value`

Comment: Are statistics up to date on the tables?

Comment: Since you tried setting MAXDOP in the query, then you don't have to think about it at higher levels (db, resource governor, instance). The query level takes precedence. What about compatibility level for the database? I'm thinking that or different statistics between the two databases.

Comment: Compatibility level is the same for both databases, statistics are on auto and up to date, any other ideas?

Comment: You should include both the plans in your question